# как решить проблему с ошибкой foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
if (isset($_GET["module"]) and  $_GET["module"]== "kabinet") {
$str = file_get_contents('http://localhost/ras/api/kab.php?module');
$mas = json_decode($str,true );
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Кабинеты</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php
        foreach($mas as $result):
    ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $result['nomer'];?></td></tr>
    <?php endforeach; 
} ?>
</table>
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Как ее решить и в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а вы уверенны что переменая $mas не пуста?, проверяли?

Comment: На каждом из этапов var_dump. Сначала посмотри что в $str, если переменная не пустая посмотри как распарсился JSON, просмотрев $mas

Answer (score 2):

В переменной `$mas` ничего нет, а точнее либо `null`, либо `false`. Проверяй на наличие в ней данных, прежде чем запускать цикл.

Причин может множество:

- ошибки парсинга `json` строки
- вообще не получены данные через `file_get_contents`
- прочее...

Answer (score 0):

Используй такой вариант.

```
foreach((array) $mas as $result)
```